# How to seperate definition and implementation of a derived class constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor, derived-class

I would like to learn how to define a derived class constructor in one file so that I could implement it in another file.

```
public:
Derived(std::string name) : Base(name);
~Derived();
```

Destructor works as expected, however with constructor I either add {} at the end (instead of a semicolon) and then get redefinition of 'Derived' error or I get asked to add {} instead of a semicolon. What is a way to separate definition and implementation in this case?

Comment: The `: Base (name)` bit is part of the definition. If you just want a declaration, that would be `Derived(std::string name);`.

Comment: I think you meant, "separate _declaration_ and _definition_".  For the rest of us "definition" and "implementation" are the same thing, and it's "declaration" that represents the implementation-less thing you inappropriately called "definition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base.h

```cpp
#include <string>

class Base
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    ...
public:
    Base(std::string name);
    virtual ~Derived();
    ...
};
```

Base.cpp

```cpp
#include "Base.h"

Base::Base(std::string name)
    : name(name)
{
    ...
}

Base::~Base()
{
    ...
}
```

Derived.h

```cpp
#include "Base.h"

class Derived : public Base {
    ...
public:
    Derived(std::string name);
    ~Derived();
    ...
};
```

Derived.cpp

```cpp
#include "Derived.h"

Derived::Derived(std::string name)
    : Base(name)
{
    ...
}

Derived::~Derived()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of base destructor being virtual?

Comment: @VytautasK [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors). It's so that if you delete a `Derived` object by calling `delete foo;` where `foo` is a `Base*` pointer whose pointed-to object is a `Derived` instance, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate declaration and definition like so:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
   Derived(std::string name); // declaration
   // ... other members here
};
```

Then, elsewhere:

```
// definition
Derived::Derived(std::string name) : Base(name) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it the same way as for any other member function of the class. For example,

**base.h**

```
#pragma once 

#include <string>

class Base 
{
    std::string name;
    public:
        Base() = default;
        Base(std::string pname);//declaration
        //other members
};
```

**base.cpp**

```
#include "base.h"
#include <iostream>
//definition
Base::Base(std::string pname): name(pname)
{
    std::cout<<"Base constructor ran"<<std::endl;
    
}
```

**derived.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "base.h"
class Derived : public Base
{
  public: 
    Derived(std::string pname);//declaration
};
```

**derived.cpp**

```
#include "derived.h"
#include <iostream>
//definition
Derived::Derived(std::string pname): Base(pname)
{
    std::cout<<"Derived constructor ran"<<std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "derived.h"
#include "base.h"

int main()
{
    
    Derived d("anoop");
    return 0;
}
```